# Create an Array of Objects for Patch Notes in React

Tags: object-oriented, array, react.js, jsx

I was looking to get some reviews of my code, so I can improve my writing. Functionally it works the exact way I want it to based on my patch notes .md file. I'm open to all suggestions for improving the code, especially in making it more performant.

```js
 state = {
  open: false,
  notes: null
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.getData();
 }

 getData = () => {
  axios.get(patchnotes_md_urlpath)
   .then((response) => {
    const updates = response.data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').split('### ');
    let i;
    let j;
    let notes = [];
    for ( i = 1; i < updates.length; i++ ) {
     let update = updates[i].split('* ');
     const newObj = Object.assign({});
     newObj.version = update[0];
     let list = [];
     for ( j = 1; j < update.length; j++ ) {
      list.push(update[j]);
     }
     newObj.notes = list;
     notes.push(newObj);
    }
    this.setState({
     notes
    });
   }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
   });
 }
```

```js
### 0.1.2

* Patch notes now implemented when the modal starts.
* Added top lists for organizations

### 0.0.1

* Patch Notes Added
* Modal to include Patch Notes
```

Comment: Could you edit with an example markdown file you would be using?

Comment: Added an example .MD file.

Answer (score 1):

You got the first step right by removing every white space and line breaks from your string. Next you will have to remove the first occurence of `###` by splitting your string and then [slicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) out the first element.

When done, you will have to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the result of your split. Map will create a new array the exact same size of your input and apply the same function on every attribute of it.

You will then have to split each update by the `*`. When done, you can get the first value of your array with [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). This function will give out the first element of your array and delete it from the array, only leaving the notes that are going to be put in the `notes` variable :

```js
const data = '### 0.1.2\n* Patch notes now implemented when the modal starts.\n* Added top lists for organizations\n### 0.0.1\n* Patch Notes Added\n* Modal to include Patch Notes'

const updates = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, '').split('### ').slice(1).map(update => {
 updateData = update.split('* ')
 return {
  version: updateData.shift(),
  notes: updateData
 }
})

console.log(updates)
```

You can then put this function in the `.then` of your axios call